# Access privileges of private members

Tags: c#, oop

We cannot access a private variable of a class from an object, which is created outside the class, but it is possible to access when the same object is created inside the class, itself. why??

class Program
{
    private int i;

```
public void method1()
{            
    Program p = new Program();
    p.i = 5;        // OK when accessed within the class
}
```

}

class AnotherClass
{

```
void method2()
{
    Program p = new Program();
    p.i = 5; //error because private variables cannot be accessed with an object which is created out side the class
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you asking [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228825/can-we-access-a-private-variable-using-an-object) again? What's wrong with all six of the answers to your previously-posted one?

Comment: @BoltClock: At first I was going to say "nice catch!" but then I noticed you yourself had edited the last one, so obviously you'd recognize the dup. :) Nice catch anyway, though!

Comment: @BoltClock: Sorry for duplicating. But I am not satisfied with the 6 answers. Infact no one got my point. So that I posted it again. Could please clarify my doubt??

Comment: Please edit your previous question to explain what exactly you'd like to be clarified on, and I'll see if I can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this [Access Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's a design consideration of OO that allows classes to only expose the functionality that they wish to be re-used by other classes (as public / protected methods) and to keep some functionality internal to the class and not re-usable.