# Setting properties with {} braces when instantiating

Tags: c#, instantiation

Anyone knows why the following will not compile? The setter for ID is supposed to be private for both classes, so why can we instantiate ClassA but not ClassB?

```
public class ClassA {
    public string ID { get; private set; }

    public void test() {
        var instanceA = new ClassA() { ID = "42" };
        var instanceB = new ClassB() { ID = "43" };
    }

    public class ClassB {
        public string ID { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`test()` is a member of `ClassA`, so it has access to the private members (and the setter) of A. It does *not* have access to the private members or setters of `ClassB`, hence the error on instanceB but not instanceA.

For more on accessibility of private members, I encourage you to see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737602/why-and-how-does-c-allow-accessing-private-variables-outside-the-class-itself-wh/5737657#5737657) on a related question.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, intuitively I thought the private accessor restricted access to within the instance itself, rather than to any object of the same class. 
Is there any specific c# keyword to achieve this (instance level "privacy")? Do you know of other programming languages where private has the meaning I assumed?

Comment: @Erwin, I would not be able to intelligently comment about other languages (and can only sparsely comment intelligently about C#). I will just say that it's sort of a matter of trust. If a *type* can't be trusted to deal properly with its own internals, who can?

Comment: I think in C++ you can set a class as a friend class, which can access internals of another class:  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class

Answer (score 3):

Your `Test` method is in `Class A` so that can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

`Class B` is inside `Class A`, `A` cannot access private members of `B` just because of the composition.