# Why can't I access private field in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out why I cannot access the private field in the class Program?

```
class Program
{
    int marks;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        Program p = new Program();
        int s = p.marks;
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are in the same type. If you had created a different type with a private field you could not access it in type `Program`.

Comment: @LearningMath because it's in the same class where you'r using it, private fields are available in class where they'r defined

Comment: Isn't this breaking the encapsulation rule?

Comment: No, it's encapsulated within that class. Why should the class not have access to its own stuff?

Comment: Why on earth perfectly valid questions(even if too simple) on stackoverflow get downvoted? I can't understand.

Comment: Do you mean why does C# have class scoped private variables and not object scoped private variables?

Comment: @LearningMath - it's not getting downvoted because it's too simple. As you can see from Idle_Mind's post below, the answer is right in the definition of 'private', which should have been very easy to find, given a little research. One downvote reason (shown if you hover on a question's downvote arrow) is that no research was shown.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are referencing it from within the same type. If you had created a different type with a private field you could not access it in type `Program`.

> Isn't this breaking the encapsulation rule? – LearningMath

No. Encapsulation is done by defining types. The method `Main` and the field `marks` all exist in the same type `Program`.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the private field `marks` inside the scope (class) where it is declared - in your case the class `Program`.

It doesn't matter, if it is a static method or other instance of the class. The following would also be perfectly fine

```
class Program
{
    int marks;
    public int foo()
    { 
        Program p = new Program();
        return p.marks;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See [private](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private):

> Private members are accessible only within the body of the class or
>   the struct in which they are declared

Your variable is declared inside class `Program`, and that is where you are accessing it from.

Answer (score 1):

The `Main()` method is a member of the `Program` type, and therefore has access to `private` members.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to think of it is that, the created object is of the same type of the class inside which is created.

**Another thing to clarify the usefulness of accessing private members as in this case**, think in the case where you want to do a deep cloning by implementing IClonable, then you may need to copy all the values of the object including the private members. If private members are not accessible you might be unable to perform the cloning fully (deeply).

In addition, this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5231603/2696230 mentioned a thoughtful point which is

> the restriction is on the class level not on the object level.

In other words, private members are not accessible outside their classes, not inside, as the case here where you're are still inside the class which is of the same type of the created object.

Answer (score 0):

Because you still in the same Program class if you are in another class your code would work and this code can be manipulated to do the job but not recommended